# How to construct HTML as per the given structure

Tags: jquery

I need to construct the following HTML dynamically

```
<tr>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">A<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">B<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">C<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">D<span></span></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" >E<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">F<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" >G<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">H<span></span></label></td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see each tr should contain only **4 columns**

This is my code

```
var myarray = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var html = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
        {
                html += '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">' + myarray[i] + '<span></span></label></td>'
        }
        $("#mytable tbody").append(html);
});
```

As you can see from the code i am just adding up td's to the table , but couldn't make it as per the mentioned structure and the array size is also not fixed (it can be any number of elements )

This is my fiddle

Could you please let me know how to add as each tr should contain only 4 elements only

https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/701/

Comment: You will also need to handle column spans when your array length isn't evenly divisible by 4. Some hints for you: use the modulus operator (`i + 1 % 4 == 0`) to know when to start a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check the `index`, make sure the remainder of `4` is `0` (where `4` being natural index obtained by `i + 1`):

```js
var myarray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    html += '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">' + myarray[i] + '<span></span></label></td>';
    if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
      html += '</tr><tr>';
  }
  $("#mytable tbody").append('<tr>' + html + '</tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```js
var myarray = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var html = ''
      
        for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length;)
        {
        html+="<tr>";
         for(var j=4; j>=1; j--){
                html += '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">' + myarray[i++] + '<span></span></label></td>';
                }
                   html+="</tr>";
               $("#mytable tbody").append(html);
               html='';
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="mytable">
   <tbody>
    
   </tbody>
</table>
```